# How do I get a Quip Document ID the Quip Live App resides in?

Tags: quip, liveapps

Is it possible to get the Quip document ID the Quip Live app is instantiated in? If yes, what's the API?

Answer (score 1):

quip.apps.getThreadId is what you want per https://nscom.quip.com/dev/liveapps/documentation#record-properties-and-data

I know you asked for documentID but I'm assuming you meant threadID.